# Bootstrap form confusion

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not quite understanding the following:

1. What is the 'for' in "for=inputEmail" referring to?
2. Is the "inputEmail" in the 'id' a bootstrap specific name or can I change that to whatever I want? kind of like changing a class or id? Same thing?

Thank you everyone!

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
   <div class="controls">
  <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `label for` associates the label with the input, so that clicking on the label focuses the input, and screen readers can read the content appropriately.
2. The `id` is under your control; it's not a special Bootstrap name.  Note that the `label for` and the `input id` must match, so if you change one you should change the other as well.

Comment: As @RichieHindle mentioned The issue(clicking on label bring focus to the corrsponding input) is because of the use of "for" and "id" connection with the label and the corresponding input field.I solved the issue in my page after seeing his answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

That refers to your text inputs id of `inputEmail`. It lets the browser know what input that label is for.

If you were to click on that label, your focus would be put on that text input.

Also, yeah, that id is totally up to you, just make sure the `for` in the label matches the `id` in the input!

Answer (score 0):

A label can be bound to an element by using the `for` attribute. I don't think it's going to be problem if your `for` attribute in the label matches `id` attribute in the input.